# How to use Consistency and bounded variance to imply asymptotically unbiasedness?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference, asymptotics, unbiased-estimator, consistency

I saw this question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239146/consistency-and-asymptotically-unbiasedness

Let $Y_1,Y_2,\dots$ be a consistent sequence of estimators for a random variable $X$. Assume a uniform upper bound on the variance. Then consistency implies asymptotic unbiasedness.

But I do not why he got
$$\mathbb E[|Y_n-X|]\leq \epsilon+\sqrt{\mathbb E [|Y_n-X|^2]\mathbb{P}[|Y_n-X|\geq\epsilon]}\to 0.$$

Comment: Here is what a search for *consistency* and *asymptotic unbiasedness* yields on Cross Validated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22asymptotic+unbiasedness%22+consistency